# Inaccuracy in Plot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, precision-and-accuracy

This problem might be well-known - in this case, I would appreciate a link, because I could not find anything. My problem: A certain function (super long and nasty expression) needs to be plotted. However, it seems that there is some weird coloring problem. The code goes like (`f` is really very long and it does not happen with shorter expressions. I dont think it is reasonable to show the form of `f`)

```
Plot3D[f,{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10},
  PlotRange->All,
  Ticks->{{-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9},{-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9},{1,3,5}} 
  AxesStyle->Directive[Thick],
  Boxed->False, 
  TickStyle->Directive[Thick,Black,14],
  LabelStyle->Directive[Black,20],
  PlotStyle->Directive[Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Opacity[0.9],
  ColorFunction->"Rainbow",
  PlotPoints->80, 
  Viewpoint->{-1,1.5,1.5}
]
```

PlotPoint does not seem to be the problem, since doubling them does not help.

See the plot to understand the problem. 
[image: plot with weird colloring issue]
This black fuzzy stuff should not be there. I dont know how to better describe it. Any experiences with this? Thanks!

Comment: Without the definition of `f`, it's hard to diagnose or cure the problem you see! But does specifying a non-default value for option `MaxRecursion` help at all?

Comment: I believe these are shadows from the `Lighting`. Try adding the option `Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}`.

Comment: Yep, I've seen it before.  Cannot make sure what will fix it without `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Without the function my best guesstimate is that you are seeing shadows from the `Lighting` option.

```
SeedRandom[4328]
ListPlot3D[RandomReal[1, {9, 9}],
 InterpolationOrder -> 2,
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 Mesh -> None]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice above that there are some dark areas of shadow.  There are many settings for `Lighting` but a basic setting to rid your plot of shadows is `Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}`.

```
SeedRandom[4328]
ListPlot3D[RandomReal[1, {9, 9}],
 InterpolationOrder -> 2,
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 Mesh -> None,
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now notice that the shadows are gone.

Hope this helps.